# Coulomb potential from QFT in the external field approximation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, dirac-delta-distributions, propagator

In eq. (13.6.8) at page 558 of the first volume of the Quantum Theory of Fields by Weinberg, the following identity is given:
\begin{align}
\left[\frac{1}{(q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)((q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)...((q_1+...+q_{N-1})\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}+\text{permutations}\right]\delta((q_1+...+q_N)\cdot p)=(2\pi i)^{N-1}\delta(q_1\cdot p)\delta(q_2\cdot p)...\delta(q_{N-1}\cdot p)\delta(q_{N}\cdot p).
\end{align}
Weinberg suggests a proof of the identity based on the Fourier transform of a certain partition of unity. That proof is indeed easy to carry out. I am looking at another way to prove the same identity. Consider $N=3$; then the lhs of the first equation reads
\begin{align}
&\Bigg[\frac{1}{(q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)((q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}+\frac{1}{(q_2\cdot p +i \varepsilon)((q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}+\frac{1}{(q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)((q_1+q_3)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)} \\
&+\frac{1}{(q_2\cdot p +i \varepsilon)((q_2+q_3)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}+\frac{1}{(q_3\cdot p +i \varepsilon)((q_1+q_3)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}+\frac{1}{(q_3\cdot p +i \varepsilon)((q_2+q_3)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}\Bigg]\delta((q_1+q_2+q_3)\cdot p). 
\end{align}
Using the constraint imposed by the Dirac delta function, one can re-express all propagators in terms of $q_1$ and $q_2$\begin{align}
&\Bigg[\frac{1}{(q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)((q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}+\frac{1}{(q_2\cdot p +i \varepsilon)((q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)} \\
&+\frac{1}{(q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)(-q_2\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}
+\frac{1}{(q_2\cdot p +i \varepsilon)(-q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)} \\
&+\frac{1}{(-(q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)(-q_2\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}+\frac{1}{(-(q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)(-q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}\Bigg]\delta((q_1+q_2+q_3)\cdot p). 
\end{align}
What I would have expected to be able to do now is using the distributional identity
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{x-i\varepsilon}-\frac{1}{x+i\varepsilon}=2\pi i \delta(x)
\end{equation}
to get to the final result on the rhs of the first equation. However, it seems some extra manipulation is needed. Could you show me a derivation (even for fixed $N=3$) of the initial identity that uses the distributional identity of the Dirac delta function instead of the method suggested by Weinberg?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to arrive at the result; starting from
\begin{align}
&\Bigg[\frac{1}{(q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)((q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}+\frac{1}{(q_2\cdot p +i \varepsilon)((q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)} \\
&+\frac{1}{(q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)(-q_2\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}
+\frac{1}{(q_2\cdot p +i \varepsilon)(-q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)} \\
&+\frac{1}{(-(q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)(-q_2\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}+\frac{1}{(-(q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)(-q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}\Bigg]\delta((q_1+q_2+q_3)\cdot p). 
\end{align}
Now combine under one denominator the first term of the first line with the first term of the second line and the second term of the first line with the second term of the second line:
\begin{align}
&\Bigg[\frac{1}{(-q_2\cdot p +i \varepsilon)((q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}+\frac{1}{(-q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)((q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)} \\
&+\frac{1}{(-(q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)(-q_2\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}+\frac{1}{(-(q_1+q_2)\cdot p +i \varepsilon)(-q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}\Bigg]\delta((q_1+q_2+q_3)\cdot p). 
\end{align}
Doing the same operation again
\begin{align}
&\Bigg[\frac{-2\pi i\delta((q_1+q_2)\cdot p)}{(-q_2\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}+\frac{-2\pi i\delta((q_1+q_2)\cdot p)}{(-q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}\Bigg]\delta((q_1+q_2+q_3)\cdot p) \\
&=\Bigg[\frac{-1}{(q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}+\frac{-1}{(-q_1\cdot p +i \varepsilon)}\Bigg]2\pi i\delta((q_1+q_2)\cdot p)\delta((q_1+q_2+q_3)\cdot p) \\
&=(2\pi i)^2 \delta(q_1\cdot p)\delta((q_1+q_2)\cdot p)\delta((q_1+q_2+q_3)\cdot p)=(2\pi i)^2 \delta(q_1\cdot p)\delta(q_2\cdot p)\delta(q_3\cdot p).
\end{align}
It looks a bit tedious but it works. Of course I would be happy to hear if there are any smarter suggestions.